# refresh embedded image vaadin

Tags: java, html, image, vaadin

I have following code to show a picture in an embedded picture in Vaadin

```
final Embedded currentPicture = new Embedded("Profile picture of " + strusername);
File uploadedPicture = new File(alreadyUploaded);
currentPicture.setSource(new FileResource(uploadedPicture));
```

This is just a small part of a larger project so this is just a snippet.

The code works fine but gives problem with caching. I know that I can counter the caching by adding a random factor to the URL of the image, but I can't seem to get it working with an embedded picture.

For instance: the value of `alreadyuploaded` is "/path/to/pic/user.jpg" and Vaadin shows the image as following: `http://my.project/picture/APP/global/0/legacy/0/user.jpg` when I check the HTML code.

When I refresh I see another picture (still not the right one) and the link is as following:
`http://my.project/picture/APP/global/7/legacy/7/user.jpg`

Another refresh results in:
`http://my.project/picture/APP/global/9/legacy/9/user.jpg`

Is there any way I can add a random element to an embedded picture? The [example](https://vaadin.com/book/-/page/components.embedded.html) of the Book of Vaadin doesn't work since I don't have streamresource because I used [this upload picture example](https://vaadin.com/book/-/page/components.upload.html) on the Book of Vaadin